# click, drag, and resize events getting mixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a div that I want to apply `click`, `drag`, and `resize` events to. However, when I start end a drag, the click event is activated (same with ending a resize). Does anyone know how to avoid this?

My code looks something like this:

```
$("#foo").click(function() {
     //click handler
});

$("#foo").draggable({
     stop: function() {//dragstop handler}
});

$("#foo").resizable({
     stop: function() {//resizestop handler}
});
```

When I finish dragging an element, both the `dragstop` and `click` handlers are called. Same with resize and click. Any ideas on how to avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `click` event is firing when you remove your finger from the mouse button, you can use this to your advantage. You can set a flag in the other event handlers that states they were used, and if so then you can just not run the code in the `click` event handler:

```
var doClick = true;
$("#foo").click(function() {

     //check if the other event handlers were used, if they were then doClick will equal false and this `if` statement will resolve to false
     if (doClick) {
         //run code for click event handler here
     } else {
         //setup the flag for next-time
         doClick = true;
     }
}).draggable({
     stop: function() {

         //set flag to disallow click event handler
         doClick = false;
     }
}).resizable({
     stop: function() {

         //set flag to disallow click event handler
         doClick = false;
     }
});
```

Also notice that I changed the calls to the `$('#foo')` selection so the element doesn't have to be selected three times (just once now).

Comment: The only issue with this is that it disables the next (actual) click if after the resize your mouse ends up outside the element (because of a maxwidth, or going out of the window). I solved this by only preventing the next click if $(".ui-resizable-e").is(":hover")

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem a couple days ago, and here's how I solved it. Not sure if it's the best way to go about it though. Basically you bind the `mousedown` and `mouseup` events to your element as well, so that on `mousedown`, you disable the click handler, and on `mouseup` you renable the handler. You probably also want to define your click callback function elsewhere so you can reference it without having to use duplicate anonymous functions:

Here's a JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/uQGMu/

```
var clickHandler = function () {
    alert('clicked');
};

$("#foo").click(clickHandler);

$("#foo").draggable({
    stop: function() {
        alert('stopped dragging');
    }
});

$("#foo").bind('mousedown', function() {
    $('#foo').unbind('click', clickHandler);
});

$('#foo').bind('mouseup', function() {
    $('#foo').bind('click', clickHandler);
});
```

​